# C++ Win32 Prevent window Activation allow input

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, win32gui

I am trying to make a custom On screen keyboard for an existing application (that i have no control over)

The program I intend to use it with only needs certain keys (numbers + some letters) and is being used in a touch screen environment

however as screen real estate is at a premium, using the built in on screen keyboard is out of the question.

as such i am trying to make a simple GUI based one using Win32, however i can't seem to find a way to prevent the window from being activated (being the window in use) without also stopping my being able to receive input from said window.

i have tried creating the window with flags to prevent activation - WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
however when i do this i dont seem to be able to receive my simulated input in another program.

i know my input code works (tested using a sleep and then clicking other window)

i have also tried using ShowWindow to remove activation from the window after the buttonpress, but to no avail.

my code simplified is:
main.cpp:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winable.h>

#include "resource.h"

BOOL CALLBACK DialogProc(HWND H,UINT M,WPARAM W,LPARAM L)
{
    switch(M)
    {
        case WM_INITDIALOG:
        {
            return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
          EndDialog(H,0);
          return TRUE;
        }
        case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            ShowWindow(H, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
            switch(LOWORD(W))
            {
                case A_KEY:
                    {
                        //Sleep(500);
                        INPUT ip;
                        // Set up a generic keyboard event.
                        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
                        ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
                        ip.ki.time = 0;
                        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
                        // Press the "A" key
                        ip.ki.wVk = 0x41; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
                        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
                        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                        // Release the "A" key
                        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
                        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
                        return TRUE;
                    };
            }
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    return DialogBox(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(DLG_MAIN), NULL, (DLGPROC)DialogProc);
}
```

resource.h:

```
#include <windows.h>
#define DLG_MAIN 1000
#define A_KEY 2000
```

resource.rc:

```
#include "resource.h"

DLG_MAIN DIALOG 0,0,300,111
CAPTION ""
STYLE WS_VISIBLE|WS_CAPTION|WS_SYSMENU|WS_EX_TOPMOST|DS_SETFOREGROUND//WS_EX_NOACTIVATE
BEGIN
    CONTROL "A", A_KEY, "Button", WS_VISIBLE, 2, 2), 20, 20
END
```

Any advice on where i'm going wrong/what else to try?

Thanks

James

Comment: Handle the `WM_MOUSEACTIVATE` message and return `MA_NOACTIVATE`.

Comment: i've tried adding an extra case under the switch(M) section, doing that and it still doesnt work, the window still takes focus and i get an error ding telling me off for type where i can't, is that the correct place to put that case?

Comment: Remember that to return a value from a dialog procedure you need to use `SetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, DWLP_MSGRESULT, <value>);` rather than simply returning it.

Comment: did not know that - just starting to learn C/C++, but now my whole dialog disappears when i press a single button, and no text is entered?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about other requirements you may have, but reading your post, I imagine you could use the [RegisterRawInputDevices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645600(v=vs.85).aspx) functionality, which allows you to retrieve input information from a window that is not active. In addition, you message loop may not defer “a lot” from the code you posted, as you can use the WM_INPUT message to process the input information.

Instead of placing a code snippet in this reply, I will add a link to the [MSDN examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645546(v=vs.85).aspx) (which have a code snippet). The example may guide you to all the related functionality available in the Win32 API to retrieve raw input data.

Regarding the windows focus, you can use the WS_EX_NOACTIVATE style when creating your window, as you will still receive the WM_INPUT messages after registering for raw input.

Finally, please notice that you may have other challenges with the OS now that Windows has extra support for on-screen virtual keyboards (TabTip).

Comment: ok, i've tried to follow what you've suggested, but when i try to compile i get an error:'RegisterRawInputDevices' was not declared in this scope, i've tried to research from MSDN and know that i have to add the following includes: windows.h, winuser.h, and i have had to define WM_INPUT to the value on MSDN, i'm using codeblocks and the gcc compiler, any idea where i'm going wrong?

Comment: Hi @JamesKent, the RegisterRawInputDevices function is defined inside Winuser.h, but you should only need to include Windows.h, as it also includes the Winuser.h header file. Is the "was not declared in this scope" the only error message you received?

Comment: @james, do you have the Microsoft’s Platform SDK installed and properly set (both headers and libs)? I have not been using CodeBlocks/GCC for a long time, but here are two codeblocks wiki and forum links to set the [global compiler settings for the Platform SDK](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=275.0) and [VC++ compiler](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Installing_a_supported_compiler#Microsoft_Visual_C.2B.2B).

Comment: i tried installing the SDK, (7.0) and followed the instructions in that link, but it still wont compile with either GCC or VB2010, if i use GCC i get an error in one of the headers about including another header - sal.h that doesnt exist, and if i use VB2010 i get a lot more warnings and then it fails when it gets to RegisterRawInputDevices, saying identifier not found.

Comment: @JamesKent, could you remove the "#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN", so that Windows.h includes all headers? In addition, I would require you to share your source code in order for me to try compiling it and give any further help.

Comment: i did try removing the "#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN", that didnt make a difference, i did some digging and i think it's because i was trying to use the express edition i dont have that header, trying to set up the pro edition to try that, and what i posted above was my source code, i was trying it with a single key before i bothered to write the rest, no sense doing it twice...